# Executing the intents manually and get its result

Tags: android

I'm very new to Android programming and I wish I could do this:

1)Create a new Intent

2)Execute the Intent and get its result as string.

Something like:

```
Instrumentation.ActivityResult ar = new Instrumentation.ActivityResult(1, new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL,Uri.parse("tel:" + ussd)));
```

I wish the intent :

```
new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL,Uri.parse("tel:" + ussd))
```

need to be executed and get its result.

I tried with `getResultData` which is just giving the:

```
Intent { act=android.intent.action.CALL dat=tel:xxx-xxx-xxxx }
```

But I want to get the *data* out of it. Data I mean the data that will be displayed when this ussd executed normally.

Is is possible?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: refer this link:http://docs.vacau.com/reference/android/app/Instrumentation.ActivityResult.html

Comment: actually you want to get the xxx-xxx-xxxx  from getResultData  right?

Comment: I guess yes!! But I'm not sure whether my intent is got executed in first place!

Comment: Try this:                             Instrumentation.ActivityResult ar = new Instrumentation.ActivityResult(1, new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL,Uri.parse("tel:" + ussd)));
       Uri uri=ar.getResultData().getData();
     String str=uri.toString();
     System.out.println("str: "+str);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I wish the intent new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL,Uri.parse("tel:" + ussd)) need to be executed and get its result.

There is no "result" for "executing" that `Intent`, for any likely definition of your term "execute".

> Data I mean the data that will be displayed when this ussd executed normally.

That "data" is displayed to the user. It is not available to developers.

Comment: Thanks for your response. There is no way I can read that response? Any sort of hack?

Comment: I thought of doing this. Android (looking into the source) does call `execStartActivity` and `sendActivityResult` for sending the result to the current thread. I thought of copy those methods and rewrite them according to my need and call those method manually. But I see I couldn't able to access `execStartActivity` in any way. Are there any ways for it do so atleast?

Comment: @batman: "Are there any ways for it do so atleast?" -- you can download the Android source code, modify it as you see fit, compile the results into a ROM mod, and install that ROM mod on your own device. That will be required because, as I wrote, there is no "result" for "executing" that `Intent`, any more than "executing" an `Intent` for Angry Birds will return an egg.